# How can I check the number of AJAX calls being made, in an integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, testing

I have a remote form, which disables the submit button while the AJAX request is in progress. I'd like to check that if I stress click the button, no other AJAX requests will be done. How could I check this in an integration test?

Comment: It's not an automated test, but you can easily check on the requests with firefox and the [firebug addon](http://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check active ajax calls with jquery

```
$.active
```

If you use capybara for integration tests

```
page.evaluate_script('$.active').should be <= 1
```

might be a solution.

As you probably don't know when calls occur 
a helper function might do the trick

```
def test_until(seconds=5)
  start_time = Time.now
  while (Time.now - start_time) <= seconds do
    yield
    sleep 0.05
  end
end
```

wich can be called like this

```
test_until do
  page.evaluate_script('$.active').should be <= 1
end
```

Thus you test for 5 seconds if there are ever more than one active ajax call

Answer (score 1):

Keep a global or a static variable. Increment the variable inside the function called by Ajax and check what will be the value of your variable. It should never exceed one, guaranteeing that Ajax call is made only once.

If you are onto automated testing, this provides you more info on checking number of ajax calls active and other stuffs.

http://hedleyproctor.com/2012/07/effective-selenium-testing/

Hope this helps. Thank you.